# Forbidden Error

Tags: php, wordpress

I have an error in my wordpress blog, when i click on any page's link that occured.\

```
Forbidden
You don't have permission to access /category/uncategorized/ on this server.
Additionally, a 403 Forbidden error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument    to handle the request.
```

please tell me what should i do to solve it. thanks

Comment: please post your .htaccess and also the file-permissions on .htaccess

Comment: there is no .htaccess file in my blog's folder

Comment: empty .htaccess file is in blog's folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your Permissions: [Changing File Permissions « WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_File_Permissions)